# Does the phase of an electronic ground state wavefunction matter in a numerical calculation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, computational-physics

Does the phase of wavefunction matter in a numerical calculation?

Recently, I was trying to solve a simple model system using numerical grid-based methods and saw that the phase of the ground state was sensitive to changes in the parameters of the numerical grid. I found that the ground state wavefunction $\Psi_{0}(x_{1}, x_{2})$ was flipped by a phase a factor of $e^{i\pi}$ in some cases.

Why would this happen?

For example, consider a 1d model of a 2e- atom, with a Hamiltonian (in atomic units)
$$
\hat{H}(x_1, x_2) = \sum_{i=1,2}\left[ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\text{d}^{2}}{\text{d}x_{i}^2} -\frac{Z}{x_i}\right]+ \frac{1}{x_1 - x_2}  
$$
where $x_{1}, x_2 $ are position variables of the electrons and Z is the atomic number of the 2$e^{-}$ atom.

Comment: You probably know that a constant phase factor has no physical significance (and if you didn't, I think the answer is "it doesn't matter"). For any deeper answer explaining why the phase you find depends on the parameters you are using, you should probably include more information than "numerical grid-based methods" on how you are solving the system.

Comment: If you only ever need each eigenfunction alone, then you can use the fact that the global phase change does nothing. But if you ever need to overlap integrate one eigenfunction against another, you should find some way to fix the phases so that you do not end up with weird spurious results.

Comment: @Puk the point is why would that happen in the case of the numerical solution? I am bothered about what naturallyIconsistent is saying. I suspect that there's some issue with why the amplitude for $\Psi_{0}$ is negative in the ground state.

Comment: And I'm saying if you want answers explaining why this is happening, you should tell us more about the method you are using to obtain your solution. Positive and negative $\Psi_0$ are equally valid.